# Apache POI not rendering output in excel for every column

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache POI for reading data from database and rendering to excel. I used Oracle db. 
My Intended output in excel is [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaVGb.jpg)

The actual output in excel is [actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlJ7g.jpg)

In this the employee names are Devendra Singh and Yuvraj Verma. Below them are their respective token no is A1359 and A1539. R,W,FH,OTR,OTW,OTFH are their production values for each employee.

When using System.out.print the code is showing right positions but not in excel sheet. There is no exception also.

```
        //method to create cells
            private static void createCell(XSSFWorkbook wb, XSSFRow row, short column,    short halign, short valign,Object value) {
                    System.out.println("Creating row #"+row.getRowNum() + " Colm# "+column+" value "+value);
                   XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(column);  
                   cell.setCellValue(value.toString());
                   CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();  
                   if(column == 1) {
                    XSSFDataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();
                    cellStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d mmm yy"));          
                }            
                    cellStyle.setAlignment(halign);
                    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(valign);

                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            }
```

In the System.out.println() getting output as

```
            name DEVENDRA SINGH token:A1359 category:D depart:14 month:11 year:2015
            Creating row #1 Colm# 2 value DEVENDRA SINGH
            Creating row #2 Colm# 2 value A1359
            Creating row #3 Colm# 2 value R
            Creating row #3 Colm# 3 value W
            Creating row #3 Colm# 4 value FH
            Creating row #3 Colm# 5 value OT-R
            Creating row #3 Colm# 6 value OT-W
            Creating row #3 Colm# 7 value OT-FH
            Creating row #4 Colm# 1 value 01/Nov/2015
            Creating row #4 Colm# 2 value 12
            Creating row #4 Colm# 3 value 3
            Creating row #4 Colm# 4 value 4
            Creating row #4 Colm# 5 value 5
            Creating row #4 Colm# 6 value 6
            Creating row #4 Colm# 7 value 7
            Creating row #5 Colm# 1 value 02/Nov/2015
            Creating row #5 Colm# 2 value 5
            Creating row #5 Colm# 3 value 2
            Creating row #5 Colm# 4 value 5
            Creating row #5 Colm# 5 value 3
            Creating row #5 Colm# 6 value 3
            Creating row #5 Colm# 7 value 4
            Creating row #6 Colm# 1 value 03/Nov/2015
            Creating row #6 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 1 value 04/Nov/2015
            Creating row #7 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 3 value 9
            Creating row #7 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 6 value 6
            Creating row #7 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 1 value 05/Nov/2015
            Creating row #8 Colm# 2 value 3
            Creating row #8 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 6 value 6
            Creating row #8 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 1 value 06/Nov/2015
            Creating row #9 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 1 value 07/Nov/2015
            Creating row #10 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 1 value 08/Nov/2015
            Creating row #11 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 1 value 09/Nov/2015
            Creating row #12 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 1 value 10/Nov/2015
            Creating row #13 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 1 value 11/Nov/2015
            Creating row #14 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 1 value 12/Nov/2015
            Creating row #15 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 1 value 13/Nov/2015
            Creating row #16 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 1 value 14/Nov/2015
            Creating row #17 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 1 value 15/Nov/2015
            Creating row #18 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 1 value 16/Nov/2015
            Creating row #19 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 1 value 17/Nov/2015
            Creating row #20 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 1 value 18/Nov/2015
            Creating row #21 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 1 value 19/Nov/2015
            Creating row #22 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 1 value 20/Nov/2015
            Creating row #23 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 1 value 21/Nov/2015
            Creating row #24 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 1 value 22/Nov/2015
            Creating row #25 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 1 value 23/Nov/2015
            Creating row #26 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 1 value 24/Nov/2015
            Creating row #27 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 1 value 25/Nov/2015
            Creating row #28 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 1 value 26/Nov/2015
            Creating row #29 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 1 value 27/Nov/2015
            Creating row #30 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 1 value 28/Nov/2015
            Creating row #31 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 1 value 29/Nov/2015
            Creating row #32 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 7 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 1 value 30/Nov/2015
            Creating row #33 Colm# 2 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 3 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 4 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 5 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 6 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 7 value 0
            ***end****
            ***start****
            name YUVRAJ VERMA token:A1539 category:D depart:14 month:11 year:2015
            Creating row #1 Colm# 8 value YUVRAJ VERMA
            Creating row #2 Colm# 8 value A1539
            Creating row #3 Colm# 8 value R
            Creating row #3 Colm# 9 value W
            Creating row #3 Colm# 10 value FH
            Creating row #3 Colm# 11 value OT-R
            Creating row #3 Colm# 12 value OT-W
            Creating row #3 Colm# 13 value OT-FH
            Creating row #4 Colm# 8 value 2
            Creating row #4 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #4 Colm# 10 value 3
            Creating row #4 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #4 Colm# 12 value 3
            Creating row #4 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #5 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #5 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #5 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #5 Colm# 11 value 4
            Creating row #5 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #5 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 8 value 3
            Creating row #6 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #6 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 9 value 68
            Creating row #7 Colm# 10 value 8
            Creating row #7 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #7 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #8 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #9 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #10 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #11 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #12 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #13 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #14 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #15 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #16 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #17 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #18 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #19 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #20 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #21 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #22 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #23 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #24 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #25 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #26 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #27 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #28 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #29 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #30 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #31 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #32 Colm# 13 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 8 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 9 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 10 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 11 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 12 value 0
            Creating row #33 Colm# 13 value 0
            ***end****
```

Code that calls the above code is below:

```
            try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nmdckdl" ,
                                                "root" , "" );
                            //connection = DBUtility.getConnection();  
                            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("incentiveDetails.xlsx"));
                            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Individual Incentive");
                            XSSFRow row=spreadsheet.createRow(1);
                            /*Creating headers */
                            spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
                                        1, // mention first row here
                                        3, //mention last row here, it is 1 as we are doing a column wise merging
                                        1, //mention first column of merging
                                        1  //mention last column to include in merge
                                        ));          
                            createCell(workbook, row, (short) 1, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,"Date");
                            int year,month;    
                            String name,department,category,token;
                            year = 2015; month = 11;
                            String tempDt = year+"-"+month+"-01"; //yyyy-mm-dd                                          
                            java.sql.Date date = valueOf(tempDt); //convert string date to java.sql.Date
                            ProductionDetailsDao production = new ProductionDetailsDao();
                            String oracleDate = production.javaSqlDateToString(date,"yyyy-MM-dd");
                            SimpleDateFormat oracleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            String[] temp = oracleDate.split("-");
                            temp[2]= "__";
                            String temp2 = String.join("-", temp).toUpperCase();
                            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select name,token,cat,dep from indinc_t where dt like '"+ temp2 +"'  group by token  order by token asc");  
                            List<ProductionDetailsBean> productionList = null;
                            int empCount =0,i=1;
                            while(resultSet.next()) {
                               row.setRowNum(1);
                               empCount++;
                               System.out.println("***start****");
                               name =  resultSet.getString("Name");
                               token = resultSet.getString("Token");
                               category = resultSet.getString("Cat");
                               department = resultSet.getString("Dep");

                               System.out.println("name "+name+" token:"+token+" category:"+category + " depart:"+department+" month:"+month+ " year:"+year);
                               spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,i+1,i+6));

                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+1), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_GENERAL,name);
                               row=spreadsheet.createRow(2);                
                               spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2,2, i+1,i+6));              
                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+1), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_GENERAL,token);
                               row=spreadsheet.createRow(3);
                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+1), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER,"R");
                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+2), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER,"W");
                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+3), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER,"FH");
                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+4), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER,"OT-R");
                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+5), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER,"OT-W");
                               createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+6), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER,"OT-FH");
                               ProductionDetailsDao prodDao = new ProductionDetailsDao();
                               ProductionDetailsBean prod;
                               productionList = new ArrayList();              
                               PreparedStatement ps = null;
                               token = token.toUpperCase();              
                               String data,query ;              
                               int rom,waste,fh,otrom,otwaste,otfh;
                               try {
                                        query = "SELECT * from indinc_t WHERE upper(token) = ? and dep = ? and cat = ? and dt like ? order by dt";
                            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                                        if(ps == null){
                                            System.out.println("Error in setting preparerd statement...");                                              
                                        } else {                                                                  
                                            ps.setString(1, token.toUpperCase());                            
                                            ps.setString(2, department.toUpperCase());
                                            ps.setString(3, category.toUpperCase());  
                                            ps.setString(4, temp2);                      
                                            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                                            int r= 3;
                                            while (rs.next()) {
                                                    prod = new ProductionDetailsBean();                              
                                                    rom = rs.getInt("ROM");
                                                    waste = rs.getInt("WASTE");
                                                    fh = rs.getInt("FHR");
                                                    otrom = rs.getInt("ROM85");
                                                    otwaste = rs.getInt("WASTE85");
                                                    otfh = rs.getInt("FHR85");
                                                    date = rs.getDate("DT");// Date received in format yyyy-mm-dd  java.sql.Date  
                                                    System.out.println("date is "+date);
                                                    String strDt="";
                                                    if( date !=null ) {
                                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                                        strDt = sdf.format(date);
                                                   }    
                                                    r++;
                                                    row=spreadsheet.createRow(r);
                                                    if(empCount == 1) {
                                                    createCell(workbook, row, (short) empCount, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,strDt);
                                                    }

                                                    createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+1), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,rom);
                                                    createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+2), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,waste);
                                                    createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+3), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,fh);
                                                    createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+4), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,otrom);
                                                    createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+5), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,otwaste);
                                                    createCell(workbook, row, (short) (i+6), CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER,otfh);
                                            }
                                        }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }              
                               i=i+6;
                               System.out.println("***end****");    
                             }

                            workbook.write(out);
                            out.close();
                            System.out.println("incentive details.xlsx written successfully");
             }            
             catch (SQLException ex) {
                 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                Logger.getLogger(DownloadExcel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Comment: That code looks fine - maybe the bug is in some other code. Please post calling code.

Comment: @RobinGreen    Here is the calling code

Comment: @RobinGreen    Here is the calling code    
    
http://pastebin.com/6Z0g8Nn2 Sorry was not to paste the code here as character limit exceeded so using pastebin. Here I am retrieving list of employees via query and then looping through each employee to get his individual production details in second query.

Comment: Please include your pastebin code in the question. It will help future readers of this question to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call

```
row.setRowNum(1);
```

or

```
spreadsheet.createRow
```

in a loop of this kind. The first call just doesn't make sense, and the second call will overwrite the rows you have already created in the previous loop iteration. Instead, create the rows before the loop, and then retrieve them inside the loop using `spreadsheet.getRow`.

Comment: thanks it improved a little. Need a suggestion.  As told I have first created the rows and then called the setRowNum() within the loop. For row=spreadsheet.createRow(r)  ,  the rows are created as per the no of records in the database. In my current scenario I would be no of days in the particular month. Then shall create 31 rows outside the while loop in advance in general or is there some other method.

Comment: Yes, there is another way. You can create a method `getOrCreateRow` which will try to first get the row, and if null is returned, then create the row and return that. Then call that in the loop. That way you don't have to create the rows before the loop.